# Problems with setting environment variables (especially PATH) and using cd with them in cmd in windows 10

Tags: command-line, environment-variables, path

I am following a [tutorial](http://ptgoetz.github.io/blog/2013/12/18/running-apache-storm-on-windows/) to setup Apache Storm. (That's just for context -- it doesn't really matter for my error.)

So it tells me to set some environment variables, specifically `%JAVA_HOME%` and `%STORM_HOME%` as `C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\` and `C:\storm-0.9.1-incubating-SNAPSHOT-12182013\`, respectively. I've never done this sort of thing before, so I looked up how to do this and I ran:

```
C:\>setx %JAVA_HOME% C:\JAVA\jdk1.8.0_60\
```

and it gave: `SUCCESS: Specified value was saved.`

Then I did:

```
C:\>setx %STORM_HOME% C:\storm-0.9.1-incubating-SNAPSHOT-12182013\
```

and it gave the same thing: `SUCCESS: Specified value was saved.`

Then the tutorial says to add `%STORM_HOME%\bin;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\;C:\Python27\Scripts\;` to `PATH`. I entered `C:\>PATH` to see what it currently is and it gave:

```
PATH=C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
```

So I thought I could add to it by doing

```
C:\>setx PATH C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;%STORM_HOME%\bin;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\;C:\Python27\Scripts\;
```

In other words, I just tried calling `setx` on `PATH` and I set it to what it currently is and with the stuff the tutorial says appended to the end. It gave `SUCCESS: Specified value was saved.` However, when I enter:

```
C:\>PATH
```

it returns what it was originally (the stuff I tried appending is not there). I tried another method. I ran

```
C:\>PATH=%PATH%;%STORM_HOME%\bin;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\;C:\Python27\Scripts\;
```

Then when I entered `C:\>PATH` it returned the full PATH with the stuff I wanted to append appended.

The problem I now face is using these variables. When I enter

```
C:\>cd %STORM_HOME%
```

it says `The system cannot find the path specified.` I tried restarting my computer but `PATH` got reset and I still got the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@DavidPostill is correct, but doesn't actually resolve your problem. The actual answer is much simpler: Command Prompt, like any program, receives its environment variable at startup. When you set a persistent environment variable (either per-user or system-wide), you are changing the registry values that determine the environment variables for future processes. **You aren't actually changing any environment variables in the *current* process at all!**

From the SETX help documentation (`setx /?`):

> ```
>  2) On a local system, variables created or modified by this tool
>     will be available in future command windows but not in the
>     current CMD.exe command window.
> ```

There are two ways to address this. The simple one is, as the documentation indicates, start a new instance of CMD. That's easy enough, but then you won't have your command history, etc. The more complicated one is to set the local environment variables (use the `set` command). The best way to do this is actually to use `set` first, and then invoke `setx` using the current environment variables. Here's an example, from what you are doing above:

```
REM Set the local version of JAVA_HOME
set JAVA_HOME=C:\JAVA\jdk1.8.0_60\
REM Set the local version of STORM_HOME
set STORM_HOME=C:\storm-0.9.1-incubating-SNAPSHOT-12182013\
REM Append the new values to PATH
set PATH=%PATH%;%STORM_HOME%\bin;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\;C:\Python27\Scripts\;
REM Do whatever checks you want to do to confirm that those are set correctly
cd %STORM_HOME%
REM Now, save the current (local) values of the environment variables
REM to persistent storage (registry)
setx JAVA_HOME %JAVA_HOME%
setx STORM_HOME %STORM_HOME%
setx PATH %PATH%
```

Note the use of `%` characters. You use them when you went to expand an environment variable, not when you want to refer to one. The `setx` lines above are processed as "Set the user-wide environment variable JAVA_HOME to this process' current local value of JAVA_HOME", which is equivalent to saying "Set the persistent environment variable JAVA_HOME to `C:\JAVA\jdk1.8.0_60\`" because that's what %JAVA_HOME% expands to in the current process.

Comment: Thank you for this! I understand it a lot better now, and it worked too :)

Answer (score 1):

#### Why didn't SETX update my PATH

> setx PATH C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;%STORM_HOME%\bin;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\;C:\Python27\Scripts\;

Your `setx` syntax is wrong:

- Put the quotes `"` around the second parameter (the 'value').

  The second parameter should be quoted if it contains spaces and `%PATH%` almost always contains spaces.

You should be using:

```
setx PATH "%PATH%;%STORM_HOME%\bin;%JAVA_HOME%\bin"
```

Or:

```
setx PATH "%STORM_HOME%\bin;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH%"
```

---

#### Syntax

> ```
> SETX [/s Computer [Credentials]] Variable Value [/m]
>
> SETX [/s Computer [Credentials]] [Variable] /k RegistryPath [/m]
>
> SETX [/s Computer [Credentials]] /f FileName {[Variable] {/a L,T | /r oL,oT "SearchString"} [/m] | /x} [/d Delimiters]
> ```

Source [setx](http://ss64.com/nt/setx.html)

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [setx](http://ss64.com/nt/setx.html) - Set environment variables permanently, SETX can be used to set Environment Variables for the machine (HKLM) or currently logged on user (HKCU).

Comment: Very interesting. I appreciate the help! With this and CBHacking's help above I was able to figure it out. I would +1 if I could!